# maven flex build failed

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-flex

I'm trying to build a maven project in Eclipse with 2 modules the one is a java code and the other is a flex code.

The instaled maven version is 3.3.9 , the jdk is jdk7_u80.

The maven install -X command gave me the following error :

> [DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging swf from
>   ClassRealm[project>project.project:prjt-flex:01.00.00,
>   parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]] [ERROR] Internal error:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.LifecyclePhase -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.LifecyclePhase     at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:121)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be
>   cast to org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.LifecyclePhase     at

The problem seems coming with module the flex, in the following the pom.xml:

```
<properties>
        <flex.version>4.5.1.21328</flex.version>
        <template.dir>src/main/html-template</template.dir> 
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <flexmojos.version>4.0-RC2</flexmojos.version>      
    </properties>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/flex</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
                <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${flexmojos.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <fullSynchronization>true</fullSynchronization>
                    <showWarnings>false</showWarnings>
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                    <allowSourcePathOverlap>true</allowSourcePathOverlap>
                    <sourceFile>flexprojt.mxml</sourceFile>
                    <output>target/flexprojt.swf</output>                   
                    <localesCompiled>                       
                        <locale>en_US</locale>
                    </localesCompiled>
                    <includeStylesheets>
                        <stylesheet>
                            <name>style.css</name>
                            <path>assets/css</path>
                        </stylesheet>
                    </includeStylesheets>
                    <localesSourcePath>locale/{locale}</localesSourcePath>
                    <compilerSourcePath>
                        <path>src/main/flex</path>
                    </compilerSourcePath>
                    <rslUrls>
                        <rsl>{artifactId}_{version}.{extension}</rsl>
                    </rslUrls>
                    <targetPlayer>${flash.version}</targetPlayer>
                    <fonts>
                        <advancedAntiAliasing>true</advancedAntiAliasing>
                        <maxCachedFonts>20</maxCachedFonts>
                        <maxGlyphsPerFace>1000</maxGlyphsPerFace>
                        <managers>
                            <manager>flash.fonts.JREFontManager</manager>
                            <manager>flash.fonts.AFEFontManager</manager>
                            <manager>flash.fonts.BatikFontManager</manager> 
                            <manager>flash.fonts.CFFFontManager</manager>                           
                        </managers>
                    </fonts>
                    <modules>
                        <module>
                            <sourceFile>context.mxml</sourceFile>
                            <finalName>context</finalName>
                            <destinationPath>/</destinationPath>
                        </module>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
                <executions> 
                    <execution> 
                        <goals> 
                            <goal>wrapper</goal> 
                        </goals> 
                        <configuration>
                            <templateURI>folder:html-template</templateURI>
                            <parameters> 
                                <swf>${project.build.finalName}</swf> 
                                <width>100%</width> 
                                <height>100%</height> 
                            </parameters>
                        </configuration> 
                    </execution> 
                </executions> 
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
                        <artifactId>flexmojos-threadlocaltoolkit-wrapper</artifactId>
                        <version>${flexmojos.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.adobe.flex</groupId>
                        <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
                        <version>${flex.version}</version>
                        <type>pom</type>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.adobe.flex.compiler</groupId>
                        <artifactId>flex-fontkit</artifactId>
                        <version>${flex.version}</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.adobe.flex.compiler</groupId>
                        <artifactId>afe</artifactId>
                        <version>${flex.version}</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.adobe.flex.compiler</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aglj40</artifactId>
                        <version>${flex.version}</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.adobe.cairngorm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cairngorm3</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.21</version>
                        <type>pom</type>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by building the project with maven 3.1.1 version.

But i still want to build it with 3.3.9 version and i didn't know which version of flex compiler i need.

Comment: Actually i was building my flex project with 3.9.9 which has as flex version 4.5.1.21328. After that i used maven 3.1.1 and the problem solved. What is the error that you got?

Comment: getting almost same exception as you sated in your question: [ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.LifecyclePhase -> [Help 1]

Comment: i have tried to use maven 3.1.1 version in jenkins as a maven tool but it not resolve this issue and getting same problem..

Comment: which version of flex you are using?

Comment: <flexmojos.version>4.2-beta</flexmojos.version>

Comment: then can you try to upgrade the flex version as in my example. Because the error that you got is related to the incompatibility between maven and flex version, as i knew.

Comment: Also had an issue with 3.3.9 seems to work on 3.6.3 though.

Answer (score 0):

You should point your IDE to use your externally installed (on your OS) version of maven instead of using its bundled maven.